ubuntu 24 lts kenel not compatible with vmware 17.5.2 vmmon/vmnet?
My installed VMware-Workstation-17.5.2-23775571.x86_64.bundle lakes vmmon and vnet packages, but after running the command "sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all" , I got the following Error:
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Virtual machine monitor                                             done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-38-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. 
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o] Error 255
make[3]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o'
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:2926:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFCheckTrackedMPN’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2926 | HostIFCheckTrackedMPN(VMDriver *vm, // IN: The VM instance
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3046:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFWritePhysicalWork’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
3046 | HostIFWritePhysicalWork(MA ma,             // MA to be written to
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3205:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFStartTimer’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
3205 | HostIFStartTimer(Bool rateChanged,  //IN: Did rate change?
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:271:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘LinuxDriverInit’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
271 | LinuxDriverInit(void)
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:339:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘LinuxDriverExit’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
339 | LinuxDriverExit(void)
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:117: vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-38-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. 
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/driver.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/hub.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/userif.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/netif.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/bridge.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/procfs.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/smac.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/netif.c:173:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetNetIf_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
173 | VNetNetIf_Create(char *devName,  // IN:
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/userif.c:1091:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetUserIf_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
1091 | VNetUserIf_Create(VNetPort **ret) // OUT
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:87:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetUserListener_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
87 | VNetUserListener_Create(uint32 classMask,  // IN: the listener's class mask
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/bridge.c:258:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetBridge_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
258 | VNetBridge_Create(const char *devName, // IN:  name of device (e.g., "eth0")
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1411:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetBridgeSendLargePacket’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
1411 | VNetBridgeSendLargePacket(struct sk_buff *skb,        // IN: packet to split
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumAndCopyToUser+0x2d: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled
LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/Module.symvers
CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. 
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-igsDyr/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
Can someone help please!

This is a totally unformatted unreadable worlds longest sentence. Please edit so someone may be able to help you.

Learn how to write in Markdown first. Use towrite code. And 3x ``` at the beginning and at the end to end` the code.

Extraordinarily unhelpful comments.  YES it is poorly formatted. and YES it is easy to see what the problem is.  It happens to be the same problem I have:
crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build make[3]:
The issue is changes in how the link phase and objtool work on vmmon.ko and vmmet.ko.  Building vmmon.ko fails with the above error.  Because vmware is unable to load both vmmon and vmnet, it refuses to run.
I don't have a solution, and am also looking for a solution.

I'm having the same issue.
VMware 17.05
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

For some reason this is still one of the top results on Google for this error.
I found solutions at the following sites after finding this post.
https://community.broadcom.com/vmware-cloud-foundation/question/vmware-workstation-pro-1752-on-ubuntu-2404-lts-compile-errors
cd /tmp
sudo bash
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd vmware-host-modules
git switch workstation-17.5.1
make
make install

Other useful links may be these ones.
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1434/how-to-fix-vmware-workstation-player-kernel-unable-install-modules
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773558/vmware-vmmon-vmnet-17-5-1-and-linux-kernel-6-8-0-wont-compile
